# MediaWiki sortable HTML table, not wikicode table

Tags: mediawiki

Does the wikimedia sortable table class work with HTML tables with class="wikitable sortable"? 
I can't find in the documentation. Using version 1.28.1

I added the sortable class and it doesn't do anything.

```
<table class="wikitable sortable">
 <tr class="column-header"><td>Name</td><td>Desc</td></tr>
 <tr><td>item 1</td><td>item 1 descr</td></tr>
 <tr><td>item 2</td><td>item 2 descr</td></tr>
</table>
```

Could I be missing CSS or javascript somewhere? It creates the table correctly with the styling but it's not sortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done as I found out, the top row has to have **th** elements:

```
<table class="wikitable sortable">
 <tr class="column-header"><th>Name</th><th>Desc</th></tr>
 <tr><td>item 1</td><td>item 1 descr</td></tr>
 <tr><td>item 2</td><td>item 2 descr</td></tr>
</table>
```